# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-lpthread

Tags: c++11, ubuntu, binary

I was compiling my cpp binary files but I got following errors. I have searched a lot on internet but cannot find a solution.

> g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/boost/asio -I/usr/include/boost -o
>   binary.out main.cpp connection.cpp connection_manager.cpp
>   mime_types.cpp reply.cpp request_handler.cpp request_parser.cpp
>   server.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread-lpthread

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-lpthread

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have searched for lboost_thread-lpthread in the system and found it in the following location

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0

OS: ubuntu:16.04

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a space between -lboost_thread and -lpthread in your command line.